# IWorkbenchPart.openEditor() not opening custom editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm designing an Eclipse plugin designed around a new perspective with an editor that stores code/comment snippets upon highlighting them. The parts to it include: the perspective, the editor, and a mouselistener.

I have the perspective made and can open it. I have the editor class code constructed, however, on programmatically opening the editor via `IWorkbenchPart.openEditor()` my custom editor does not seem to be initialized in any way. Only the default Eclipse editor appears. I can tell because my custom mouse events do not fire.

I used the vogella [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEditors/article.html) as a reference.

Why is my editor's `init()` method not being called upon being opened? I can tell it is not since the print statement in both `init()` and `createPartControl()` are not executed.

In googling this problem, I found a number of hits but they all revolved around error messages encountered (can't find editor, can't find file, ...). I am getting no error messages, just unexpected behaviour. So those articles were useless.

(I would ideally like a `TextViewer` instead, since I don't want them editing the contents in this mode anyway, but I decided to start here.)

Code below.

Perspective:

```java
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPageLayout;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveFactory;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;

public class PluginPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    @Override
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(true);
        layout.setFixed(true);

        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
        IEditorInput iei = page.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput();
        try
        {
            // Open Editor code nabbed from Vogella tutorial. 
            // He creates an action to do so - I force it to happen when the 
            //   perspective is created.

            // I get the name of the current open file as expected.
            System.out.println(iei.getName());
            page.openEditor(iei, myplugin.PluginEditor.ID, true);
            // This message prints, as expected.
            System.out.println("open!");
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }

    }

}
```

Editor: (Removed the other basic editor stubs (isDirty, doSave) since they are not pertinent)

```java
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorSite;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor;

public class PluginEditor extends EditorPart implements MouseListener {

    public static final String ID = "myplugin.plugineditor";

    @Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
            throws PartInitException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("editor init!");
        setSite(site);
        setInput(input);

    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("editor partcontrol!");
        //TextViewer tv = new TextViewer(parent, 0);

        //tv.setDocument(getCurrentDocument());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // nothing?
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // grab start location?
        System.out.println("down!");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // do stuff!
        System.out.println("up!");
    }

    // to be used for grabbing highlight-selection grabbing later
    public IDocument getCurrentDocument() {
        final IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .getActiveEditor();
        if (!(editor instanceof ITextEditor)) return null;
        ITextEditor ite = (ITextEditor)editor;
        IDocument doc = ite.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(ite.getEditorInput());
        return doc;
        //return doc.get();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered your editor within your plugin.xml?

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
         <editor
               default="false"
               id="myplugin.plugineditor"
               name="name">
         </editor>
   </extension>
```

Also, you may want to implement `IEditorInput` to have specific input for your editor.

Comment: Yes sir I have. For what its worth, I'll edit with my .xml when I get home. However, I'm pretty sure I misunderstand what an IEditorInput is then - the example of one on vogella seems to do nothing important, and further research/trial-error just tells me its what document you want to open with the edtior?

Comment: Editor input as name implies provides custom input for your editor. In 'init' method you can cast editor input to your own implementation, retrieve necessary data and update editor accordingly. For example, you can provide some user id in Editor input, then in init method get it, load user from DB by this id and show information about concrete user in the editor. Also, editor input is used to restore editor from memento (based on memento information you may create your editor input). But also check plugin.xml, may be you have a misspelling somewhere.

Comment: I shall, even though I'm sure eclipse added .xml stuff for me automatically, but more on the EditorInput - since all I want to do is display the raw text in the current file anyway, I shouldn't need a custom EditorInput, right? Otherwise, I could try again with a do-nothing EditorInput for sure.

Comment: Well, there is a following statement: "Based on the equals() method of the IEditorInput the system will determine if the corresponding editor is already open or if a new editor must be opened.". That means, that if you using existing editor input, it may be so that Eclipse will treat it as already opened editor, and thus will not open it. I would still suggest you to create your own EditorInpput object and pass it like this: `page.openEditor(new DummeEditorInput(), myplugin.PluginEditor.ID, true);`

Comment: Oh shoot, I thought that was for the EditorID passed in, not for the EditorInput. I have a feeling this might do it. I'll check when I can!

Comment: That did indeed fix the problem of opening the editor. Now I have to figure out why the on-click isn't working. Thank you so much!